# Multivariable logic truth table

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> (a) Write a truth table for $f(x, y, z) = x + y + z \pmod{3}$, where
>   $x, y, z$ are booleans. There should be two outputs.
>
> (b) Draw the circuit for $f$.

I don't understand how the problem expects you to have two outputs. Shouldn't each $(x, y, z)$ only give one output? (i.e. the sum mod 3?). For example, $(0, 0, 1)$ should give the output $1$.

Where's the second output coming from?

Comment: Presumably the idea is the outputs are also Booleans but $1+1+0=2 \pmod 3$ is not a Boolean.

Comment: yeah I was also confused about this. I don't understand how to do this problem, or how we can compute $x + y + z \pmod{3}$ with two outputs

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that the two outputs are the two bits you are going to need when representing either of the $3$ possible answers.

That is, when $x + y + z \pmod{3} = 0$, you should output $00$, when it is $1$, output $01$, and when it is $2$, output $10$

So, you have one sub-circuit for the first bit, and another sub-circuit for the second bit.